# How could I access the current, not emitted, data while Kinesis Analytics is processing tumbling time windows

Tags: real-time, amazon-kinesis, serverless

With AWS Kinesis Analytics, I can do stream aggregation into time blocks in an easy serverless fashion. On demand, I want to be able to show the data real-time, including the data that is still being aggregated.

How would I do that? Preferably without spinning servers? Or is this just not what Kinesis is for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect more than one consumer to your Kinesis Stream. If you want to work serverless, you may connect a Lambda that might do your on-demand tasks. Turn it on/off using [this API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_UpdateEventSourceMapping.html).

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but the idea of connecting another consumer to the stream for more fine grained data may just work for me.